# Rspec using bad grammar in test output

Tags: rspec

I have this in a spec file:

```
shared_examples_for "all pages" do
  it { should have_selector('h1', text: "heading") }
end
```

Rspec produces the following output:

> should ***has*** css "h1" with text "heading"

But I would prefer:

> should ***have*** css "h1" with text "heading"

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`have_selector` is not an RSpec matcher. I'm guessing you're using Capybara, in which case any pull request should go to that project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to their dev repo https://github.com/rspec/rspec-dev and fork it and modify the documentation as you want and give them a pull request! I hope they will find it useful and accept it. Cheers!

**EDIT:** Or else you can always fork their repo make those changes and push it to your copy and reference it explicitly inside your gemfile.